# jquery .map is not working on IE 10

Tags: internet-explorer-10, jquery

I have this jquery code:

```
$("#tf_zoom").live("click", function () {
    var n = $(".tf_thumbs").find("img").attr("src");
    var modelid = n.substr(43);
    $.post("models/get_gallery", {
        "modelid": modelid
    }, function (data) {
        var imagespathes = $(data).map(function (key, url) {
            return ({
                href: '<?php echo base_url();?>assets/uploads/files/' + url
            });
        });
        console.log(imagespathes);
        $.fancybox.open(imagespathes);
    }, "json");
});
```

and this is my html:

```
<div id="tf_thumbs" class="tf_thumbs">
    <span id="tf_zoom" class="tf_zoom"></span>
    <img id="dynam" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/uploads/files/<?php echo $firstthumb;?>" alt="Thumb1"/>
</div>
```

Okay, now my problem is that this code is not functioning on **IE 10** and surprisingly it's working like a charm on **IE 9, IE 8, IE 7** besides **FF and Google Chrome**

I read many things about this issue but nothing worked for me.
So, is there any solution for it.
your help is really appreciated.

**Update 1** : I am using jquery version **1.7**

Comment: @ArunPJohny - 1.7 - because I have to.

Comment: remove parenthesis in the return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this hint will help you:

I have noticed that `.map( $("select").get(0).options )` will not work in IE10 but `.map( $("select:first >option") )` will. This is because in ie10 .options returns a select node with an iteration of options.

So see what data is returning in IE10, perhaps it too is not an array. And if so perhaps you can do something like `$(new Array(data)).map(...` which will satisfy all browsers

Answer (score -1):

You should be using static map function for this:

```
$.map(data, function(obj, index){...})
```

See documentation [**here**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/).

```
    // If data looks like this: [{ url: 'TestUrl' }]
    // This should work:

    var imagespathes = $.map(data, function(element){
        return { href: '<?php echo base_url();?>assets/uploads/files/' + element.url };
    });
```

Comment: What data type is 'data' parameter? How does it look?

Comment: It's hard to tell what to correct without seeing structure of that object. See updated answer. You data should be an array of objects. If you like to iterate through all values. If it's plain object you are iterating through all properties of the object.

Comment: really thank you for your replies. also not working on all browsers.
the object `data` is `["e439e-bg5.png", "72308-bg4.jpg"]`

Comment: and imagepathes is `href
 

"http://localhost/mala/assets/uploads/files/e439e-bg5.png"

 
title
 

""

 
type
 

"image"`

Comment: OK, check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jEc2V/ this has to work. Also, you don't need parenthesis around object that you are returning.

Comment: You probably have some other problem. I can not help you if you can not provide the link with the problem.

Comment: okay.. anas.lapp.co is the demo website. when you enter click on Models link then you will find a thumbnail on the left of each picture. this thumbnil has a mini zoom button. this zoom button is working on all browsers but IE10

Comment: Thanks for the link. It works for me on IE10 same way as chrome. It's just second model returns empty array. But behavior is still the same as other browsers. Do you have any plugins in your IE10?

Comment: are you for real? OMG. I have to test it on another PC. Thanks for the feedback. I'll get back to you soon.

Comment: OKay I tried it on other PC's it works but not right. it brings one picture regardless to the request. It's simply insane.