# select2 "data-ajax--url" in IE10 not working, what to do?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I have :

```html
<select data-ajax--url="/SourceListe/GetItemsJson" id="SelectCat"></select>
```

```js
initSelect2($("#SelectCat"), {
    minInputLength: -1,
    data: function (term) {
        return {
            IdListe: lIdListe,
            CodeDossier: pCodeDossier,
            Parent: lCellImpact,
            OrderBy: "Numero"
        }
    },
    processResults: function (data) {
        return {
            results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                return { id: item.Identifiant, text: item.Valeur };
            })
        };
    },
});
```

This works in all browsers except IE10. I do not know why. It simply doesn't go into the controller where I put a breakpoint and it doesn't go into `processResult`. Please help!

Comment: Probably it's duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16328772/jquery-map-is-not-working-on-ie-10)

Comment: that's not my case, unfortunately!
I even can delete $.map(), and leave it like this:
processResults: function (data, page) {
      return {
        results: data.items
      };
    },

Comment: ah, sorry. You're right! I don't know if it works: can you try data-ajax-url (which is deprecated probably)

Comment: Oh booooy, that works. I saw it before, event was looking in Select2.min.js file, and that's what I found: `"Select2: The `data-ajax-url` attribute has been changed to `data-ajax--url` and support for the old attribute will be removed in future versions of Select2."`. That's why did not even try it! Damn it!

Comment: That's great that it helped you! Unfortunately with IE sometimes they're still using deprecated things... So you never know.

Comment: `data` and `processResults` should be under an `ajax` property, as those are AJAX-specific. That might be part of the problem here. You also might be using jQuery 1.x, which [has a problem with `--` in data attributes](https://select2.github.io/options.html#are-options-with-nested-configurations-supported).

Comment: @KevinBrown I've tried:
`ajax: {
    url: "/SourceListe/GetItemsJson",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: function (term) {
        return {
            IdListe: lIdListe,
            CodeDossier: pCodeDossier,
            Parent: lCellImpact,
            OrderBy: "Numero"
        }
    },
    processResults: function (data) {
        return {
            results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                return { id: item.Identifiant, text: item.Valeur };
            })
        };
    },
  },`
Still nothing!

Comment: @AlexanderB. yeah man, thanks a lot to you!

Comment: @KevinBrown, right, I'm using jQuery 1.10.2. Should I upgrade it to newer version, to avoid the future unexpected problems under different browsers?

Comment: @AlexMcManns If you do not need to support older versions of IE, I would highly recommend upgrading to jQuery 2.x. The issue has not been fixed in jQuery 1.11.3, as the patch landed in jQuery after that release.